# What can be reflected by the $C^0$-limit of Riemannian metrics?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M^n$ be a closed connected smooth manifold and {$g_i$} be a family of smooth Riemannian metrics on it  such that $g_i$ $C^0$-converges to the smooth Riemannian metric $g$ on $M^n$.

Can it possible that some geometric invariants of $g_i$  go to zero or infinity?  Does $C^0$-convergence imply the measured  Gromov-Hausdorff convergence or Gromov-Hausdorff convergence?

If the scalar curvature of $g_i$ have a uniformly lower bound, then Gromov showed that the scalar curvature of  $g$ also has the lower bound.

Comment: Clearly $C^0$ convergence implies GH convergence. I would try computing what happens to curvatures and other geometric quantities when $g_i=f_i g$ where $f_i$ is a sequence of positive smooth functions that converges to $1$ in $C^0$ but not in $C^\alpha$, $\alpha>0$ .  For simplicity assume $f_i=1$ outside a small disk.

Comment: Let $f$ the closest distance between two conjugate points. Then we can have $f(g_i)\rightarrow 0$ even though $g_i\rightarrow g$ and $f(g)>0$.